# pyqt app crashing when function is executed

Tags: python, pyqt

i wanted to make an rpc changer with pypresence and pyqt and its working, but it crashes whenever i run function that updates the presence - no errors, no exit codes it says that app doesnt respond.
i tried to use qt threading but it didnt work i also tried making it just a normal function, not a loop and it didnt work either.
any ideas?
and heres the code:

```
from pypresence import Presence 
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

start = int(time.time())
client_id = "997609359427260416"
RPC = Presence(client_id)
RPC.connect()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(485, 425)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1f1f1f;""font: 75 8pt \"Arial\";")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.onclick())
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 350, 161, 51))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #a30b00;""color: white;""transition: 0.25s;""font: 12pt;""border-radius: 8px;""")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 251, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;""font: 18pt")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 40, 91, 16))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #a30b00;""font: 12pt")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 321, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);""border: 2px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);""border-radius: 5px;""color: white;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 121, 16))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: white;""font-size: 12pt")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 321, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);""border: 2px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);""border-radius: 5px;""color: white;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 121, 16))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: white;""font-size: 12pt")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 230, 321, 31))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);""border: 2px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);""border-radius: 5px;""color: white;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 210, 121, 16))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;""font-size: 12pt")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 290, 321, 31))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);""border: 2px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);""border-radius: 5px;""color: white;")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 270, 121, 16))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;""font-size: 12pt")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def onclick(self):
        value1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        while True:
            RPC.update(
                    large_image = "large", #name of your asset
                    large_text = "test",
                    details = value1,
                    state = "Presence Changer",
                    start = start,
                    buttons = [{"label": "kndxiu on TikTok", "url": "https://tiktok.com/@kndxiu"}, {"label": "Website", "url": "https://kndxiu.xyz"}] #up to 2 buttons
            )
            time.sleep(100)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Discord RP Changer"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by kndxiu."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Errors? If no, what's the exit code? Sometimes you don't see the error in the console, it just crashes.

Comment: @puncher no exit codes and no errors, it just says that app doesnt respond

Comment: Can you add it to the post?

Comment: @puncher okay, done

Comment: No, I mean you said "it just says that app doesnt respond", can you add this message to the post.

Comment: @puncher i did, i edited my post and added what i said in my comments

Comment: You shouldn't try to edit uic files.  Also you are running an infinite loop that calls time.sleep over and over.  Time.sleep freezes the gui completely.  as does a while true loop in most cases

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, i used qtimer and replaced onclick function with this:

```
def onclick(self):
        value1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        def updateLoop():
            RPC.update(
                    large_image = "large", #name of your asset
                    large_text = "test",
                    details = value1,
                    state = "Presence Changer",
                    start = start,
                    buttons = [{"label": "kndxiu on TikTok", "url": "https://tiktok.com/@kndxiu"}, {"label": "Website", "url": "https://kndxiu.xyz"}] #up to 2 buttons
            )
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(updateLoop)
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.start()
```

and ofc `from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer` at the top and it works fine, without freezing